# Ancestor query - missing events

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-apps-activity

Is there any reason, why activities queried by `ancestorId` does not return all activities for particular file? When I use `fileId` to query activities, I can see all *singleEvents* for given file. However, when I use `ancestorId` to query activities, I can not find some of them.

If I change **groupingStrategy** from `driveUi` to `none` I can see the missing events in *combinedEvents* (each event has own *combinedEvent*), but why some of them are not included in *singleEvents* when using ancestor query along with `driveUi`, when the are present in file query with `driveUi`?

**EDIT**

Maybe these details will help to figure out where is the problem:

**service user:** personC, **file owner:** personA

**activity2**

```
2016-01-04 23:17:16, edit, personA 
2016-01-04 23:14:16, edit, personA 
2016-01-04 23:11:03, edit, personA
2016-01-04 23:08:03, edit, personB 
2016-01-04 23:05:02, edit, personA 
2016-01-04 23:02:02, edit, personB
2016-01-04 22:59:02, edit, personB 
2016-01-04 22:56:02, edit, personB 
2016-01-04 22:53:01, edit, personB
2016-01-04 22:47:46, edit, personA •
2016-01-04-22:44:46, edit, personA •
2016-01-04 22:41:46, edit, personA •
2016-01-04 22:38:46, edit, PersonA •
2016-01-04 22:35:47, edit, personA •
2016-01-04 22:30:32, edit, personA •
2016-01-04 22:27:32, edit, personA •
2016-01-04 22:24:32, edit, personA •
```

**activity1**

```
2016-01-04 22:18:29, create, personA
```

• missing event in ancestor query

Changing service user to personA or personB has no impact on result.

Comment: There's still uncertainty on my part, but from what I understand the visibility of the result will depend on the permissions set by the object (based on the [Activity API overview](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/#api-overview)).

As for the [`groupingStrategy`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list#parameters), `driveui` will return a grouped action, so that may be a key point for some events not being returned.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've just checked persmissions of the file, not found anything that can cause this problem. Also, I'm using the same settings to query by `ancestorId` and query by `fileId` - same useremail to initialize `Appsactivity` service, same  _groupingStrategy_ `"driveUi"`. With `fileId` query, I can see all the activities, but when I exchange `fileId` by `ancestorId` some of the singleEvents are not returned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's probably not the Google Drive API you are working with, but the activities API.

Activities API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/
Drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk

If you take a close look at the activity parameters (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list#parameters) you can see this:

- **drive.ancestorId**: Identifies *the Drive folder* containing the items for which to return activities.
- **drive.fileId**: Identifies *the Drive item* to return activities for.

*Your problem seems to be that you are looking at activities on the folder vs activities on the individual file*

**How to solve this**
If you query the folder for all files and loop through them, if you combine all the `fileId`'s activities you will have all activities on files in a folder.

Comment: hi, drive.ancestorId is designed to retrieve all activities under given folder from whole subtree. As you mention, querying activities for each file can solve the problem, however it will require more api calls (even if batch requests are used). Im looking for answer why it does not behave like it should.